# Any good codes to generate TOC from HTML heading elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableofcontents

I'd like to generate TOC like below in JavaScript:

```
<ol>
  <li>Heading 1</li>
  <li>Heading 2
    <ol>
      <li>Heading 2-1</li>
      <li>Heading 2-2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Heading 3</li>
</ol>
```

And the HTML codes to generate the TOC above:

```
<section id="toc">
  <p>This will be replaced with generated TOC.
</section>

<article>
  <h1>Heading 1<h1>
  <p>Bla bla bla.</p>

  <h1>Heading 2<h1>
  <p>Bla bla bla.</p>

    <h2>Heading 2-1<h2>
    <p>Bla bla bla.</p>

    <h2>Heading 2-2<h2>
    <p>Bla bla bla.</p>

  <h1>Heading 3<h1>
  <p>Bla bla bla.</p>
</article>
```

I'm really stuck :(
How do you write the code to generate the TOC? I prefer jQuery or pure JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

This was quite tough for me, but somehow I suppose I've done:

```
  $(function () {
    var assigned_level = 0,
        current_level = 0,
        id_number = 1,
        parent_node = "article",
        toc_html = '';

    $(parent_node + " *").each(function () {
      if (this.nodeName.length === 2 && this.nodeName.charAt(0) === "H") {
        $(this).attr("class", "heading");
      }
    });

    $(".heading").each( function () {
      current_level = this.nodeName.charAt(1);

      $(this).attr('id', "toc-" + id_number);

      // Close a list if a same level list follows.
      if (assigned_level !== current_level - 1) {
        toc_html += "</li>"
      }

      // Open parent lists if a child list follows.
      while (assigned_level < current_level) {
        toc_html += "<ol>";
        assigned_level += 1;
      }

      // Close child lists and the parent list if
      // the same level parent list follows.
      while (assigned_level > current_level) {
        toc_html += "</ol></li>";
        assigned_level -= 1;
      }

      toc_html += 
        '<li><a href="#' + this.id + '">' + $(this).html() + "</a>";
      id_number += 1;
    });

    // Close everything
    while (assigned_level > 0) {
      toc_html += "</li></ol>";
      assigned_level -= 1;
    }

    $("#toc").html(toc_html);
  });
```

I still don't understand what I've done :P Perhaps there's more sophisticated ways.
Please point me out anything you've found.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I've added the jQuery tag, since you're okay with using jQuery. That'll get a lot more eyes on it.

Comment: This feels a **lot** like a "please write this for me" pseudo-question. If you're stuck, that suggests you've tried something. Show us what you've tried, and we'll be happy to help you figure it out.

Comment: Wow. So many comments. Thanks everyone and sorry for silly question. Yes I'm lazy :P

Comment: Having a look at an [HTML5 Outliner](http://code.google.com/p/h5o/) might help.

Answer (score 4):

first of all, you need to close your h1,h2 tags =)

if you do `$("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")` you'll get the tags in the same order they appear on the document. So you could do a loop on that array and check the level. e.g: if the last tag was H1 and you find a H2, it means that you need to create a `<ol>`. On the other hand, if you have a H3 and the next one is an H2, it means that you need to close the `<ol>`.

The hardest part would be to close the remaining `<ol>` in the end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *"The hardest part would be to close the remaining `<ol>` in the end."* Nah, just keep a counter, increment it when opening an `ol`, decrement it when closing one, and at the end loop until it's `0`. This is all only relevant if the OP writes a solution that creates markup in a string and then inserts the whole thing into the document (which will tend to be faster); if you build it up object-by-object, obviously you don't have to worry about closing tags as there are no tags (just elements).

Comment: ahh object-by-object!!! how come i didn't think of that? i've been working too much on server side XD thxs @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Well, the thing is, building up a large markup string and then plopping the whole thing into the DOM at once is usually faster -- perhaps a **lot** faster -- than building up a DOM tree object-by-object. So if I were doing this, I'd be doing pretty much what you said, building up the markup (probably in an array, though whether that helps varies quite a lot by browser), then dumping the whole thing in at once (if in an array, using `.join('')` to create a single string).

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to go too into depth at the moment until we see what you've come up with so far.

However, look into [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/). These should give you some ideas of how to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 8 years old, but here's a proposition.
Probably not the most efficient way to do it, nor the shortest, but it works.

- First I get an array of all the headings.
- Then I prepare that array by adding the level, id and parent of each heading.
- Then I transform that array into a recursive, hierarchical one.
- Then I generate the HTML ordered lists.
- Then add the list into the TOC.

In the end of your page, add the following JavaScript:

```
// prepare the array by adding level, ID and parent to each item of the array
function prepare( array ) {
    let idt, level, t;
    for( let i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++ ) {
        t       = array[ i ];
        t.el    = t;
        level   = parseInt( t.tagName[1], 10 );
        t.level = level;
        t.idt   = i + 1;

        if( level <= 1 ) t.parent = 0;
        if( i ) {
            if( array[ i - 1 ].level < level ) {
                t.parent = array[ i - 1 ].idt;
            } else if( array[ i - 1 ].level == level ) {
                t.parent = array[ i - 1 ].parent;
            } else {
                for( let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j-- ) {
                    if( array[ j ].level == level - 1) {
                        t.parent = array[ j ].idt;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

// transform a flat array in a hierarchical array
function hierarchical( items ) {
    let hashTable = Object.create( null );
    items.forEach( item => hashTable[ item.idt ] = { ...item, subitems : [] } );
    let tree = [];
    items.forEach( item => {
        if( item.parent )
            hashTable[ item.parent ].subitems.push( hashTable[ item.idt ] );
        else
            tree.push(hashTable[ item.idt ]);
    });
    return tree;
}

// return an UL containing each title in a LI and possibly other items in UL sub-lists.
function add_list( titles ) {
    let li, a, anchor;
    let ol = document.createElement( "ol" );
    if( titles && titles.length ) {
        for( t of titles ) {
            if( t.el.id ) anchor = t.el.id;
            else anchor = t.el.textContent;
            if( ! anchor ) anchor = "inconnu";
            anchor = anchor.replace( /\W/g, "" );
            t.el.id = anchor;
            li = document.createElement( "li" );
            a  = document.createElement( "a"  );
            a.href = `#${anchor}`;
            a.innerHTML = t.el.textContent;
            li.append( a );
            if( t.subitems && t.subitems.length ) {
                li.append( add_list( t.subitems ) );
            }
            ol.append( li );
        }
    }
    return ol;
}

//get the toc element
let divtoc = document.getElementById( "toc" );

// get the article element
let article  = document.getElementById( "article"  );
if( toc && article ) {
    let titles = article.querySelectorAll( "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6" );
    titles = prepare( titles );
    titles = hierarchical( titles );
    let ol_racine = add_list( titles );
    toc.append( ol_racine );
}
```

You'll get the intended result:

```
<section id="toc">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#Heading1">Heading 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Heading2">Heading 2</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#Heading21">Heading 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Heading22">Heading 2-2</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Heading3">Heading 3</a></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```